# Как установить WinUi 3?

Tags: winui3

Не могу установить WinUi 3. Установил весь Visual Studio вместе с проектом Reunion с нуля, все как нужно. Однако сразу при старте выскакивает такая ошибка:

**This version of Project Reunion requires WinRT.Runtime.dll version 1.6 or greater. Please update to .NET SDK 5.0.213 or 5.0.407 or later. Or add a temporary Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref reference of version 10.0.*.24 or later.**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Какая версия Visual Studio у вас? Сейчас уже Project Reunion стал WindowsAppSDK в версии 1.0 и лучше эту последнюю версию использовать